# Number of committees that can be formed with 2 categories of persons

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

An 8-persons committee is to be formed out of a group of 15 women and 12 men. In  how many ways can the committee be chosen if there must be at least two men?

Please  check my answer

I started the problem by finding all possible committees without gender concern  that is

$$\binom{27}{8}$$

and I am not sure how to find answer directly. I choose to find from the case that violates the condition that is

$$\binom{12}{3}\binom{15}{5}$$

the answer is

$$\binom{27}{8}-\binom{12}{3}\binom{15}{5}$$

Comment: I have tried to improve your text. In particular a title should be synthetic, not contain the detailed statement of the problem.

Comment: Why edit my question ?

Comment: Um,I have gotten down vote  by after someone edit my question without remove full text of my question with and make question is not clear like this Please re-edit my question

Comment: The downvote (not mine) has nothing to do with the editing of your question. I am sorry to say that I am pretty certain that the level of english is quite better now than it was at first... I think that the downvote (that I do not approve) is because your solution is far from being exact. (Ctd...)

Comment: I mean I had had  downvote  in a long time ago because it make question was not clear similiar like this question  sorry for my bad english skill

Comment: @JeanMarie that mean i must include all case that violate condition and excluede from all possible condition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- $\;\binom{12}{0}\binom{15}{8}$ committees with $0$ men.

  $\;\binom{12}{1}\binom{15}{7}$ committees with $1$ man.

Hence the number of committees with at least $2$ men is
$$
{\small{\binom{27}{8}}}-\left(
{\small{\binom{12}{0}}}{\small{\binom{15}{8}}} + 
{\small{\binom{12}{1}}}{\small{\binom{15}{7}}}
\right)
$$